# What is the cleanest way to extract custom variables from a post

Tags: custom-field

At the moment I am doing something like the following from inside the main loop;

```
$custom_values = get_post_custom_values('tenderfields');
$custom_values = unserialize($custom_values[0]);
$custom_values = $custom_values[0];
```

Then accessing them with `$custom_values['my-custom-value']`

This works fine but feels a little clunky, it feels like something there is probably already an internal call for that I am just missing?

I have looked through the docs and couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you always need **all** of post meta at once this is the way to do it.

To access post meta for specific key use [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) that will retrieve value(s) and unserialize if needed.